# Xamarin forms iOS title bar icon does not get center position right when switched on in landscape the turned to portrait

Tags: ios, xaml, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, titlebar

I have an iOS-specific issue that does not happen on Android.

If the page in an app is opened in landscape mode

[image]

and then turned to portrait the logo at the center of title bar instead of moving to the center goes off the page like this:

[image]

If it is opened in portrait and then turned to landscape then it does not move to the center or off the screen, but to the left, to be stuck around a quarter of full width.

Xaml:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         x:Class="PhotoApp.MobileApp.Views.PhotoGaleryPage">
<ContentPage.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <Color x:Key="Accent">#96d1ff</Color>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</ContentPage.Resources>
<Shell.TitleView>
    <Image
           HorizontalOptions="Center"
           VerticalOptions="Center" 
        Source="logo.png"  />
</Shell.TitleView>
```

Answer (score 0):

I advise you to use this:

```
    <ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="PhotoApp.MobileApp.Views.PhotoGaleryPage">
    <ContentPage.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <Color x:Key="Accent">#96d1ff</Color>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </ContentPage.Resources>
    <Shell.TitleView>
  <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="Center"
            Margin="{OnPlatform iOS='0,0,25,0', Android='0,0,20,0', Default=0}"
            Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Image       
            Source="logo.png"  />
   </StackLayout>
    </Shell.TitleView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Alike the above answer, you can take a try like this:

```
<ContentPage>
    <NavigationPage.TitleView>
        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalOptions="Center" Spacing="10">
            <Image Source="logo.png">               
            </Image>           
        </StackLayout>
    </NavigationPage.TitleView>
    ...
</ContentPage>
```

Just take a StackLayout to wrap the image instead of putting it in Shell.TitleView directly.

Looks like the rotation in ios caused this problem as you take advantage of Image in Shell.TitleView directly. You can imagine this: it's really in center, but the screen can't display the whole title bar, which caused the problem you have seen.